# docker-compose up OSError Invalid argument

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Its pure new installation of docker toolbox. When I am
trying call my `docker-compose up` I am getting this error.

`ERROR: .OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '.\\compose/app.yaml:compose/backend.yaml:compose/gateway.yaml:compose/proxy.yaml:compose/daemons.yaml:compose/frontend.yaml:compose/cryptonodes.yaml:compose/arke.yaml:compose/superset.yaml:compose/monitoring.yaml'`

Comment: Could you post your docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: Don't have any, can I generate some default docker-compose.yml?

Comment: In order to  docker-comopose up to do something, you need a docker-compose.yml fle describing what do you want to do